# Не получается выписать нужные данные из всех объектов одного класса в текстовый документ

Tags: java

При воспроизведению программы создается текстовый файл, в котором записываются сначала все данные о объектах. После чего при нажатии на кнопку данные из `AnimalState` должны записываться еще раз отдельно, так как они не постоянные и должны будут меняться в ходе работы программы. Но получается так что первый объект игнорируется и записываются данные только о последнем добавленном объекте. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно сделать так чтоб данные класса `AnimalState` записывались в файл о всех объектах?

Главный класс:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;


public class Save extends Application{


public void start( Stage stage ) {
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("Globe.png"));
    stage.setTitle("");

    Animal cat = new Animal();
    Animal dog = new Animal();

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setPadding( new Insets(65, 65, 65  , 65) );
    gridPane.setVgap(10);    // gap between cells
    gridPane.setHgap(10);    // gap between cells

    Button button = new Button( "Step" );
    GridPane.setConstraints( button, 0, 1 );
    gridPane.getChildren().add(new Label("Press:"));
    gridPane.getChildren().add( button );


    button.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override 
        public void handle( ActionEvent e ) {

            AnimalState.stateAnimal();

        }
    });

    button.addEventHandler( MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED,
        new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
          @Override
          public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
          }
    });

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setContent( gridPane );

        stage.setScene( new Scene( new BorderPane( scrollPane, null, null, null, 
null ) ) );

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) { 
        launch( args );
    }
}
```

Класс Animal

```
public  class Animal
{
public static  String NAME = "Cat";
public int ID = hashCode();
public static  int ADULT_WEIGHT = 10;
public static  float FOOD_QUANTITY_REQUIRED_PER_HOUR = 2; 
public static  int MAX_STARVING_HOURS_BEFORE_DEATH = 24 ; 
public static  int hoursSinceLastMeal = 3;
public static  int energyPercent = 87;
public static  int MAX_ENERGY_PERCENT = 120; 
public static  int STANDARD_SPEED = 2;
public static  int MAX_SPEED = 10;  
public static  int MAX_STAMINA = 23; 
public static  int AVERAGE_SCION_COUNT_IN_LITTER = 3;
public static  int MAX_SCION_COUNT_IN_LITTER = 6;
public static  int MAX_AGE = 15; 
public static  int MIN_BREEDING_AGE = 3;
public static  int MAX_BREEDING_AGE = 12;
public static  int MAX_AGE_IN_NEST = 1;
public static  int MIN_SELF_GOVERNMENT_AGE = 3;
public static  int age = 17;
public static  String GENDER = "male";
public static  boolean isProliferating = false;
public static  boolean isFeedingNewborns = true;
public static  String TIME_OF_BIRTH = "1999.03.08";
public static  String TIME_OF_DEATH;
public static  int weight = 3;
public static  float ENERGETIC_EFFICIENCY_PER_KILO = 3;


public int getId() {
    return hashCode();
}

public Animal() {
    new AnimalSpecification( NAME, ID, ADULT_WEIGHT, 
FOOD_QUANTITY_REQUIRED_PER_HOUR, MAX_STARVING_HOURS_BEFORE_DEATH, 
MAX_ENERGY_PERCENT, STANDARD_SPEED, MAX_SPEED, MAX_STAMINA, 
AVERAGE_SCION_COUNT_IN_LITTER, MAX_SCION_COUNT_IN_LITTER, MAX_AGE, 
MIN_BREEDING_AGE, MAX_BREEDING_AGE, MAX_AGE_IN_NEST, 
MIN_SELF_GOVERNMENT_AGE, GENDER, TIME_OF_BIRTH, TIME_OF_DEATH, 
ENERGETIC_EFFICIENCY_PER_KILO);
    new AnimalState( ID, hoursSinceLastMeal, energyPercent, age, 
isProliferating, isFeedingNewborns, weight, NAME );
}

}
```

Класс AnimalState:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class AnimalState {

private static final String FILENAME = "contacts.txt";
public String str;
private static int i = 1;

public static int ID;
public static int hoursSinceLastMeal;
public static int energyPercent; 
public static int age; 
public static boolean isProliferating; 
public static boolean isFeedingNewborns;
public static int weight;
public static String NAME;

public AnimalState( int ID, int hoursSinceLastMeal, int energyPercent, int age, boolean isProliferating, boolean isFeedingNewborns, int weight, String NAME){
    this.ID = ID;
    this.hoursSinceLastMeal = hoursSinceLastMeal;
    this.energyPercent = energyPercent;
    this.age = age;
    this.isProliferating = isProliferating;
    this.isFeedingNewborns = isFeedingNewborns;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.NAME = NAME;
    String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", ID, hoursSinceLastMeal, energyPercent, age, isProliferating, isFeedingNewborns, weight, NAME);

    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;


    try {

        fw = new FileWriter(FILENAME, true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(NAME + "Log:\n");
        bw.write("Hours Since Last Meal - " + hoursSinceLastMeal + "\n");
        bw.write("Enery Percent - " + energyPercent + "\n");
        bw.write("Age - " + age + "\n");
        bw.write("Proliferating - " + isProliferating + "\n");
        bw.write("Feeding Newborns - " + isFeedingNewborns + "\n");
        bw.write("Weight - " + weight + "\n");
        bw.write("________________________________________________\n\n");
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();
            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public static void stateAnimal(){

    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;

    try {

        String str2 = String.valueOf(isProliferating);
        String str3 = String.valueOf(isFeedingNewborns);

        fw = new FileWriter(FILENAME, true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        bw.write("Step №" + i + "\n");

        bw.write( "ID = " + ID + ": " );
        bw.write( hoursSinceLastMeal + ", " );
        bw.write( energyPercent + ", " );
        bw.write( age + ", " );
        bw.write( str2 + ", " );
        bw.write( str3 + ", " );
        bw.write( weight + "\n");
        bw.write("-------------------------------------\n\n");

        ++i;

    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();
            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: не совсем понятна проблема... если вы хотите записать несколько объектов, то затолкайте их в коллекцию и пишите коллекцию. их же несколько, тут сам бог велел. вы же используете коллекцию для хранения нескольких объектов, тогда почему вы не используете ее же для записи. а если вам надо записать в текстовый файл , то создайте метод , который в цикле обработает все данные, нахоящиеся в коллекции, преобразует их в строковую переменную с форматирующими символами и прочими прелестями, а потом добавляйте уже сформированный текст в указанной перемнной в файл. собирать можно стрингбилдером...

Answer (score 0):

Используй метод append()

```
bw.append("Step №" + i + "\n");

            bw.append("ID = " + ID + ": ");
            bw.append(hoursSinceLastMeal + ", ");
            bw.append(energyPercent + ", ");
            bw.append(age + ", ");
            bw.append(str2 + ", ");
            bw.append(str3 + ", ");
            bw.append(weight + "\n");
            bw.append("-------------------------------------\n\n");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но не помогло, все равно записывает данные только для одного (последнего добавленного) объекта.